# jquery ajax not working correctly in IE?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have written an ajax in jquery. It is working perfectly in all browsers except IE. Could anyone tell me whats wrong with the code?

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: MasterVariable.SiteUrl + "/Goals/GetAllGoals",  
        contentType: "application/json", 
        dataType: "html",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (result) {
               $(".jQGoalList").html(result);
            },
            error: function (err) {
             alert("Error = " + err.statusText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What's happening in IE? Saying that's it's not working correctly isn't enough for someone to be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem earlier. Try to use "cache:false" in your ajax.

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET", 
            url: MasterVariable.SiteUrl + "/Goals/GetAllGoals",
            contentType: "application/json", dataType: "html",
            data: "{}",
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $(".jQGoalList").html(result);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Error = " + err.statusText);
            }
        });
```

In IE "cache:false" will resolve your problem.

Comment: Why would that solve the problem presented in this question? (keep in mind that there is no clear problem presented in this question)

Comment: @KevinB with ajax I have the same prob. The ajax response was not updated in IE only, but working with all other browsers. When I set "cache:false" it was working.

Comment: Why does it work? the addition or removal of a `_` parameter shouldn't fix any *"problems"*, it will only prevent the browser from caching the response. (which again, isn't a problem, it's a feature.)

Comment: Great :) its working perfectly @NaveenChandraTiwari :)